# CURLOPT_REQUEST_TARGET with pycurl

Tags: python, curl, libcurl, pycurl

I would like to use pycurl with the option that matches `--request-target` on the command line tool.

When trying this with the following code:

```
import pycurl
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, "http://192.168.2.230")
c.setopt(c.REQUEST_TARGET, "*")
c.perform()
print(c.getinfo(c.HTTP_CODE))
```

I get the following error:

> AttributeError: trying to obtain a non-existing attribute: REQUEST_TARGET

A similar thing happens when I change `c.setopt(c.REQUEST_TARGET, "*")` to `c.setopt(c.CURLOPT_REQUEST_TARGET, "*")`

> AttributeError: trying to obtain a non-existing attribute: CURLOPT_REQUEST_TARGET

Is there a way to use `CURLOPT_REQUEST_TARGET` with pycurl?

--------------- update -------------------

User barmar below gave me a hint to look at setopt_string for setting custom options. This looks promising.
I tried this:

```
import pycurl
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, "http://192.168.2.230")
c.setopt_string(266, "*")
c.perform()
print(c.getinfo(c.HTTP_CODE))
```

This however results in the following error:

> TypeError: strings are not supported for this option

--------------- update 2 -------------------

Ended up making a [pull request](https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl/pull/784) to add the feature

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl/issues/670) for how to work around missing option constants.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. I think that this would then be the way to do it? `CURLOPT_REQUEST_TARGET = 266
c.setopt(CURLOPT_REQUEST_TARGET, "*")` 
This does however result in the following error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./example.py", line 5, in <module>
    c.setopt(CURLOPT_REQUEST_TARGET, "*")
TypeError: strings are not supported for this option`

Comment: I don't see any alternative.